# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when adding backend to project in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, sinch

I'm building a messaging app and using sinch and parse for the messaging client. We build a simple messenger following the sinch tutorial found here https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/ .

After getting that going, I added a backend following these steps: https://cloud.google.com/mobile/app_engine/add_module

At first, gradle would not build until I added `multiDexEnabled = true` to the build.gradle (*a SO post that I cant seem to find atm provided the fix.*)

So now gradle builds, and the backend successfully launches on `localhost:8080.`

But now when I run the messenger app I get

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at this line 
>   usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new
>   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() in the ListUsersActivity.

As well, I'm getting this error for the LoginActivity:

> Performing stop of activity that is not resumed:
>   {com.myapp/myapp.LoginActivity}
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed

I'm horribly confused, as the app runs fine before adding the simple backend, and the backend seems to be working. If there is something else I could provide to help track this down, please let me know. I've googled my butt off and have come up with nothing.

EDIT: Error log is below

```
04-15 12:29:02.811    4148-4148/com.myapp E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.myapp/com.myapp.LoginActivity}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.anykilline.killine/com.myapp.LoginActivity}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3356)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 12:29:03.781    4148-4292/com.myapp I/System.out﹕ ParseRequest.NETWORK_EXECUTOR-thread-1 calls detatch()
04-15 12:29:03.791    4148-4148/com.myapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-15 12:29:03.791    4148-4148/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417fcda0)
04-15 12:29:03.791    4148-4309/com.myappI/System.out﹕ ParseRequest.NETWORK_EXECUTOR-thread-2 calls detatch()
04-15 12:29:03.791    4148-4148/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 4148
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.ListUsersActivity$2$1
            at com.anykilline.killine.ListUsersActivity$2.done(ListUsersActivity.java:76)
            at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
            at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
            at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:917)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT 2:
Saw an SO post that suggested the build order could have been wonky. As such, I deleted my build folder and did a clean build. still having errors, however they have now changed:

```
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.myapp.LoginActivity$1$1', referenced from method com.myapp.LoginActivity$1.onClick
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1752 (Lcom/anykilline/killine/LoginActivity$1$1;) in Lcom/anykilline/killine/LoginActivity$1;
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0032
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3baf at 0x34 in Lcom/anykilline/killine/LoginActivity$1;.onClick
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.myapp.LoginActivity$2$1', referenced from method com.myapp.LoginActivity$2.onClick
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1754 (Lcom/anykilline/killine/LoginActivity$2$1;) in Lcom/anykilline/killine/LoginActivity$2;
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x003d
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3bb2 at 0x3f in Lcom/anykilline/killine/LoginActivity$2;.onClick
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.sinch.android.rtc.DefaultSinchClientBuilder', referenced from method com.sinch.android.rtc.Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8798 (Lcom/sinch/android/rtc/DefaultSinchClientBuilder;) in Lcom/sinch/android/rtc/Sinch;
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xf429 at 0x02 in Lcom/sinch/android/rtc/Sinch;.getSinchClientBuilder
04-15 14:09:06.889  25184-25184/com.myapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-15 14:09:06.899  25184-25184/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417fcda0)
04-15 14:09:06.899  25184-25184/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 25184
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sinch.android.rtc.DefaultSinchClientBuilder
            at com.sinch.android.rtc.Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder(Sinch.java:15)
            at com.myapp.MessageService.startSinchClient(MessageService.java:46)
            at com.myapp.MessageService.onStartCommand(MessageService.java:37)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2883)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your error log.

Comment: @user3058613 : What is ListUsersActivity and most importantly, which line of code is line 76?

Comment: please check my new edit, but to answer your question, it is an activity that lists the users on the screen, to allow you to pick which user to message. it is available to view in the sinch documentation and on github i have linked at the top of this post

Comment: I would like to mention again, that until I added this blank backend in android studio, this app was working and sending messages successfully. that is the strange part...

Comment: Hey did you get this working? If so, it would be great if you could post the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no, decided to write our own code from scratch instead. I do have an update though: this bug chooses to come and go as it pleases. No pattern that I can see as well.